# My Counter made with ChangeNotifier Provider replicates its value with other Counter Instances

Tags: flutter, dart, shopping-cart, changenotifier, flutter-change-notifier-provider

I am creating a counter for a shopping cart. The problem is when the value of one counter changes, it affects all the other counters on the screen. I used ChangeNotifier and I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

This is the Counter Model

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CounterModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  int _count = 0;
  int get getCount => _count;

  void increment() {
    if (_count >= 0) {
      _count++;
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void decrease() {
    if (_count > 0) {
      _count--;
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

This is the build of the Counter

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provide_count/counter_model.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class ProvideCount extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final counter = Provider.of<CounterModel>(context);
    return Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.add), onPressed: counter.increment),
        Text('${counter.getCount}'),
        IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.remove), onPressed: counter.decrease),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

And this is the main.dart file

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provide_count/counter_model.dart';
import 'package:provide_count/providecount.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider<CounterModel>(create: (_) => CounterModel()),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        home: SafeArea(
          top: true,
          child: Scaffold(
            body: Column(
              children: [
                ProvideCount(),
                ProvideCount(),
                ProvideCount(),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have a `ChangeNotifierProvider` at the top of your tree.

When you call `Provider.of<CounterModel>`, You are searching for the closest `Provider` widget on the tree, Which is the same for all of the widgets. So they sync up.

If you don't want this to happen, you could stop using `Provider`, or you could at least wrap each `ProvideCount` with their own `Provider`:

```
return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: SafeArea(
        top: true,
        child: Scaffold(
          body: Column(
            children: [
              ChangeNotifierProvider<CounterModel>(
                create: (_) => CounterModel()
                child: ProvideCount(),
              ),
              ChangeNotifierProvider<CounterModel>(
                create: (_) => CounterModel()
                child: ProvideCount(),
              ),
              ChangeNotifierProvider<CounterModel>(
                create: (_) => CounterModel()
                child: ProvideCount(),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: Wrapping each ProviderCount with its own provider count works. Thanks.